# Error Python The truth value of a Series is ambiguous con geodesic distance

Tags: python, booleano

Tengo una tabla en la que se almacena la longitud y latitud en dos columnas y quiero calcular la distancia con el módulo geopy.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejecuto el siguiente código y me sale el error `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`.

```
            for i in range(len(df["Latitud2"])):    
                Lat0 = df["Latitud2"].shift(-1)
                Lon0 = df["Longitud2"].shift(-1)
                Lat1 = df["Latitud2"]
                Lon1 = df["Longitud2"]
                point= (Lat0, Lon0)
                point_next=(Lat1,Lon1)
                if (distance(point, point_next, ellipsoid=(6377., 6356., 1 / 297.)).miles).all()is not none:
                       df.loc["Distancia"]=(distance(point, point_next, ellipsoid=(6377., 6356., 1 / 297.)).miles)
```

Alguien que pueda ayudarme?

Comment: Hola, Marta. Bienvenida a Stackoverflow en español. ¿Podría esto responder a tu consulta? [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o ]. ¿Estás aplicando algún or o and? ¿Intentas comprobar si existe un valor asignado con un if?

Answer (score 0):

Geopy no está pensado para realizar operaciones vectorizadas con Pandas, necesitas usar `pandas.DataFrame.apply` si quieres usar `geopy.distance.distance`.

Creo que buscas obtener la distancia entre las coordenadas de una fila y la siguiente, si es así, puedes hacer algo como:

```
from geopy.distance import distance
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def calc_distance(row):
    if row.isna().any():
        return np.nan
    return distance(
        row[["Latitud2", "Longitud2"]],
        row[["Latitud2_shift", "Longitud2_shift"]],
        ellipsoid=(6377., 6356., 1 / 297.)
        ).miles
       

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Latitud2":  (41.267778, 41.268333, 41.303056, 41.303056),
    "Longitud2": ( 2.075556,  2.075833,  2.086389,  2.086389)}
    )
    
df[['Latitud2_shift', 'Longitud2_shift']] = df.shift(-1)
df["distance"] = df.apply(calc_distance, axis=1)
df.drop(['Latitud2_shift', 'Longitud2_shift'], axis=1,  inplace=True)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>     Latitud2  Longitud2  distance
> 0  41.267778   2.075556  0.040918
> 1  41.268333   2.075833  2.457935
> 2  41.303056   2.086389  0.000000
> 3  41.303056   2.086389       NaN
> ```